# How to / What to Query to get value of current QtVirtualKeyboard Input Method

Tags: qt, qml, qtvirtualkeyboard

Can anyone tell me what property I can check to determine the active input method (i.e. handwriting, keyboard, etc.)?

Basically, I'm looking to have some logic like:

```
if (inputMethod === "handwriting") {
    //do this
} else {
    //do that
}
```

or

```
if (handwriting.active) {
    //do this
} else {
    //do that
}
```

I have read through all of the documentation for [InputMethod](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-virtualkeyboard-inputmethod.html), [InputEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-virtualkeyboard-inputengine.html), and [InputContext](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-virtualkeyboard-inputcontext.html) and, unfortunately, a description like, "provides access to an input context" isn't helpful.

It tells me what the QML type has... but not what it **is**. Additionally, within the properties of two of the three QML types, the other two QML types are accessible, which seems a bit random and circular to me and only adds to my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done several ways depending on your keyboard implementation. Easiest way I see is using [HandwritingInputPanel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-virtualkeyboard-handwritinginputpanel.html)'s active property or detect a [HandwritingModeKey](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-virtualkeyboard-handwritingmodekey.html) press.

Comment: HandwritingModeKey {
        onClicked: {
            //do this
        }
    }

Worked. Thanks